# How to restore database from azure storage container using c#

Tags: c#, azure, database-restore

We have a azure storage container where everyday we are keeping database backup files. Now we are developing an application using SMO (C#) to restore database from the Azure storage container. Restoring from the local device is working properly but I am not getting any help regarding restore from the azure container using c#.

When I use azure blob for restoring backup then I am getting following error

> Cannot open backup device
>   'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/backupcontainer/Database_e95aec6ab14a43a3a14a62f82b2c7208_20180718022621-04.bak'.
>   Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally

And my code is

```
Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
restoreDB.Database = databaseName;
BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.Url, CredentialName);
restoreDB.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;

RelocateFile DataFile = new RelocateFile();
string MDF = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[0][1].ToString();
DataFile.LogicalFileName = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[0][0].ToString();
DataFile.PhysicalFileName = smoServer.Databases[databaseName].FileGroups[0].Files[0].FileName;

RelocateFile LogFile = new RelocateFile();
string LDF = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[1][1].ToString();
LogFile.LogicalFileName = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[1][0].ToString();
LogFile.PhysicalFileName = smoServer.Databases[databaseName].LogFiles[0].FileName;

restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(DataFile);
restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(LogFile);
restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;
restoreDB.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(rstDatabase_PercentComplete);
restoreDB.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(rstDatabase_Complete);
restoreDB.SqlRestore(smoServer);
```

Can anyone help me how to restore backup file from azure storage container using c# or what is the problem of my code?

Comment: Does the server have permission to access the file?

Comment: Yes server has permission. I am providing the CredentialName (Storage container and shared access signature)

Comment: A blob in Azure Storage isn't the same as a file on a local disk; that is, it cannot be accessed via standard file I/O. It has its own SDK (or REST API). You'd need to copy the blob contents somewhere locally (e.g. VM disk) first.

Comment: But if the blob type is page blob then definitely it is possible to restore directly from the azure storage

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. SQL server 2012 or previous versions don't support Database restoring from block blob. So I updated my SQL Server to SQL Server 2017 and also changed my code. You need to create credential in SQL Server which will be used when restoring from azure.

```
                if (!smoServer.Credentials.Contains(CredentialName))
                {
                    Credential cr = new Credential(smoServer, CredentialName);
                    cr.Create("SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE", AzureDataModel.SharedAccessKey);
                }

                Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
                restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
                restoreDB.Database = databaseName;
                BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.Url);
                restoreDB.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
                restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
                if (!smoServer.Databases.Contains(databaseName)) {
                    Database db = new Database(smoServer, databaseName);
                    db.Create();
                }

                RelocateFile DataFile = new RelocateFile();
                string MDF = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[0][1].ToString();
                DataFile.LogicalFileName = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[0][0].ToString();
                DataFile.PhysicalFileName = smoServer.Databases[databaseName].FileGroups[0].Files[0].FileName;

                RelocateFile LogFile = new RelocateFile();
                string LDF = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[1][1].ToString();
                LogFile.LogicalFileName = restoreDB.ReadFileList(smoServer).Rows[1][0].ToString();
                LogFile.PhysicalFileName = smoServer.Databases[databaseName].LogFiles[0].FileName;

                restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(DataFile);
                restoreDB.RelocateFiles.Add(LogFile);
                restoreDB.NoRecovery = false;
                restoreDB.PercentComplete += new PercentCompleteEventHandler(rstDatabase_PercentComplete);
                restoreDB.Complete += new ServerMessageEventHandler(rstDatabase_Complete);
                restoreDB.SqlRestore(smoServer);
```